# Need to know how to pass a model for paypal transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

I have a simple order form that I created in mvc and when they hit the submit button, I have the user redirected to paypal for payment and then they get redirected back to the original page. I'm trying to find out how to either pass the model information or save it somehow because after payment is complete, my program sends them an email with a copy of their receipt and successful purchase. How do I go about doing this? Please let me know if there is anything else you need to see. I'm still brand new to MVC and I'm trying to figure this all out.

Model

```
public class WritingAppModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is Required.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "A Valid Phone Number is Required.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is Required.")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject is Required.")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Topic is Required.")]
    public string Topic { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Document Type is Required.")]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Urgency is Required.")]
    public string Urgency { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of Pages is Required.")]
    public Int16 NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requirements are Required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Requirements { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Writing Style is Required.")]
    public string Style { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Spacing is Required.")]
    public string Spacing { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Academic Level is Required.")]
    public string AcademicLevel { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of Sources is Required.")]
    public Int16 NumberOfSources { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is Required.")]
    [Range(0.01, 10000.00, ErrorMessage = "Your quote is not complete because you haven't completed all of the steps.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string UnFormattedPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Price.ToString();
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Currency is Required.")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what paypal api are you using?

Comment: The rest api is what I believe it is called

Comment: One of the way is to set up a webhook and receive notifications whenever a payment is complete. You can check it here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#notifications